# Memory Cache absoluteExpiration - Will this affect all entries in memory cache?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am using `MemoryCache.Default` to cache the data for some time...

I did it using the [Set method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780572.aspx)

```
DateTimeOffset cacheTimeOut = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2));
patientOrderCache.Set("abc", abcData, cacheTimeOut);
```

If the `absoluteExpiration` value is over, will it remove ALL cache entries in `MemoryCache.Default`?

Or, will it just remove the specified one (`abc`) ?

I am pretty sure it will just remove ONLY the specified entry (`abc` key and related data)...but just want to confirm as I didn't see any description related to that.. and my existing memory cache has so much of data that I am not aware of.

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, will it just remove the specified one (abc) ?

It will remove just the specified key `abc` for which you specified this expiration policy when you stored it into the cache.

The other cache entries will be subject to the expiration policy you specified when you stored them (or the default policy if you didn't specify one explicitly).